# There is way to counteract frida toolkit in android app?

Tags: android, frida, public-key-pinning, android-network-security-config

in app i use native network security config for public key pinning.

using frida toolkit our security team can bypass pinning.

the question is simple: there is any way to protect against that or not ?

Comment: There's always protection against some tampering and then there's always more tampering to circumvent the protection. It's a cat and mouse game and this question is a bit broad to give a clear answer.

Comment: @JensV yes, which are the cat against frida ? i do not want invulnerable app, bug to protect against basic use of frida

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - "yes... but"

Long answer(s)

https://github.com/darvincisec/DetectFrida

https://www.vantagepoint.sg/blog/90-the-jiu-jitsu-of-detecting-frida

https://mobile-security.gitbook.io/mobile-security-testing-guide/android-testing-guide/0x05j-testing-resiliency-against-reverse-engineering

For each one of them there is a way to bypass as @JensV said, for example;

Detecting Frida by scanning local ports and or doing the D-Bus auth dance? Start "frida-server with `--listen=unix:/path/to/sock"` and then forward the socket to a local TCP port with `adb forward tcp:27042 localabstract:/path/to/sock`. Credit: t@leonjza

Comment: thanks so much, there is any library like "rootbeer" for detect frida? each of this 3 link seams require long implementation. i don'n need a complete shiled against frida but like rootbeer a basic detection

Comment: @Xan As a rule of thumb you can say that a "basic Frida detection" also requires only "basic measurements" to bypass this check - hence it is next to useless especially if it comes form an well known library. For such libraries within days standard Frida bypass scripts will be available.

Comment: @Robert correct but library like rootbeer exists anyway.

Comment: what do you mean by library ? use of them, wrap the JNI and invoke the detection method/s before any pinning occurs.

Comment: @JimWest for library i mean something like rootbeer make for root detection. i'm not expert for this specific situation, i like something (if it exists) that can be easy used and (for the best) mantained and updated with improvement over detection.


like rootbeer.....

Comment: I think there isn't any open source lib that does detect frida like rootbeer does with detecting root.